# Overlapping Divs and simplifying jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

first is trouble with my overlapped divs, they're supposed to be overlapping each other but the thing is that upon loading the page, the box-shadow style are overlapped too, which I do not want, and would like to fix it.

the box shadow i want for each div is `box-shadow: 0 0 2px #acacac;`

but upon loading the page since there are 3 divs overlapped together the box shadow looks like it's been set to `box-shadow: 0 0 6px #acacac;`.

second is trying to simplify my jquery code.I've been trying to figure out a way to just uncheck all selected radio buttons upon checking a specific radio button, rather than having a long line of jquery code. something in the line of "if this radio button checked, uncheck  checked radio button"

heres the
      Jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/cQca5/3/)

hopefully I find a solution, thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why but I think there is a glitch in jsfiddle letting me select 3 radio buttons at the same time.

Comment: You can select them individually because they all have a different name. Also please don't ask two different questions in one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS: Simple as that. Hide all the divs and show what you want.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            $('.div_style').css('display','none');
            $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

CSS: display:none in .div_style

```
 .div_style{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #acacac;
    width:750px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #acacac;
    top:40px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:#FFF;
    }  
    #diva{
        z-index:1;
    }
    #divb{

    }
    #divc{

    }
```

HTML: the attr name should be the same. Display:block for the first div.

```
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="div1" checked> 1st</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="div2"> 2nd</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="div3"> 3rd</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div_style" style='display:block;' id="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div_style" id="div2">div2</div>
    <div class="div_style" id="div3">div3</div>
```

Heres a optimized jsFiddle solcing all the problems at once:
http://jsfiddle.net/cQca5/5/

Regards.

Comment: I've encountered a problem on the radio buttons, upon selecting a specific radio button and refreshing the page, the div that is shown is div 1 when radio button 3 is selected, is there a way to fix this??

Comment: Well of course. You have this for the first checkbox <input type="radio" name="radio" value="div1" checked> As you can see the property checked its in the first radio button. When you refresh it goes back to the original code. For that not to happen you need to use PHP for example. But I need to understand the purpose of refreshing and stay in the same check box to help you.

Comment: I was just thinking of if some user of the site accidentally pushed f5 they'd think of it as a glitch or something, well it's not really a big deal but it bothers me a bit xD So i was just looking for a solution to just reset the radio button to the 1st radio, upon refreshing the page so that'd it'd pair with the div that is shown. oh and thank you very much for the jquery fix I appreciate it very much!.

Comment: Theres ways to do it... If you're using permalinks for example. But I dont think that solution works for all browsers. What you can do it's give a warning message if user tries to refresh the page (For example): http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-stop-a-page-from-exit-or-unload-with-jquery/
DEMO: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-stop-page-from-exit.html